# Getting Mail Through `PHP IMAP`

Tags: php, imap

Here is my code for get `sent` mails

```
    $inbox = imap_open('{'.$domainURL.':143/notls}INBOX.Sent',$emailAddress,$emailPassword) or die('Cannot connect to domain:' . imap_last_error());
```

But it doesnot return sent mails..When i try to print the response it shows only the number of sent messages..below is that..

```
Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retreive  Domain Server Mail

```
{domain.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
```

For retreive  Gmail

```
{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
```

Comment: Thanks.It saves me a Lot